# How I can get the missing lines from a.txt files using diff?

Tags: diff

I have the following files:

a.txt

```
1
2
11
22
33
444
```

b.txt

```
1
2
3
11
22
33
555
```

I want to retrieve the lines from a.txt that do not exists on b.txt.

I tried with that:

```
diff a.txt b.txt -d
2a3
> 3
6c7
< 444
---
> 555
```

But I want the output to be

```
444
```

Only. Is there a way to place some sort of filters upon diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use `grep`

```
grep -f b.txt -v a.txt
```

Key `-f` will define `b.txt` as list of patterns to search in `a.txt`. And key `-v` will reverse the search  and printout line from `a.txt` where the pattern was not found.

Answer (score 1):

`diff` might be the wrong tool, use `grep` instead:

```
grep -vxf b.txt a.txt
```

i.e. get any line from `a.txt` not present in `b.txt`

Alternatively, `comm` would work by suppressing lines in both and the second file:

```
comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```